# Accessing Neo4j List in Java After Query

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I don't have much code to post, and I'm quite confused on where to start. There's a lot of documentation online and I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. 
Suppose I have this query result saved into a `StatementResult` variable:

```
result = session.run("MATCH (n:person {tag1: 'Person1'})"
                                    + "RETURN [(n)-->(b) WHERE b:type1 | m.tag2]")
```

In the Neo4j browser, this returns a list of exactly what I'm looking for. My question is how we can access this in Java. I know how to access single values, but not a list of this type.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: This query is definitely not valid !

Answer (score 0):

Usually you just iterate over the statement results, to access each record and then with each record you can access each named column. You didn't use any names.

The column will return `Value` objects which you then can turn into the types you expect, so in your case into a list with `asList()`.

See the API docs for [StatementResult](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/java-driver/current/org/neo4j/driver/v1/StatementResult.html) and [Value.asList()](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/java-driver/current/org/neo4j/driver/v1/Value.html#asList--)

also your statement is not correct you probably meant `b` where you wrote `m` and you **need to name your column to access it**